# how to re set up parent branch where we make new branch there

Tags: git

I have a branch called **FEATURE-1** and I created this branch from **staging** then:

- I push this **FEATURE-1** and got conflict,
- I rebased `git rebase` into **development**

After I already tested my FEATURE-1 and no issue so far then I could go to **staging** branch.

Unfortunately not all codes from branch **development** should into staging, but my branch **FEATURE-1** already got rebased from **development**.

To be safe better I want to get the source branch from **master** instead.

Is that possible for my branch **FEATURE-1** set up to branch **master** for the source origin?

Answer (score 1):

If you have feature 1 currently rebased on top if develop, you can move it on top of master with (using [`git merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base))

```
git rebase --onto master $(git merge-base develop feature1) feature1
```

That will take:

```
m--m--m--m--m (master)
    \
     d--d--d--d (develop)
               \
                f--f--f (feature1)
```

To:

```
              f'--f'--f' (feature1)
             /
m--m--m--m--m (master)
    \
     d--d--d--d (develop)
```